# ArcGIS Routing on Android with Network Analyst module

Tags: arcgis-server, java, network-analyst, arcgis-android

I am currently developing an Android App for navigation purposes. It is based on the ArcGIS Android API. I have an ArcGIS server (with network analyst module) with all the needed data running.

At the moment the App displays a map with the current position (point A) and has a search form, where you can search for a building (point B).

The next step would be to display a route from "point A" to "point B". Does anybody know if there is a way to do that natively with the Android API?

Also it would be possible to compute the routing information on a Java web service and then send it to the app, which only has to display it.

I cannot find any sample code on the ArcGIS resource page.

Answer (score 1):

With the new version of ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android, there is a sample project that makes route analysis.

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=26092e89af76430787774d7a1b53e1e1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet with ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android 100.9.0.

```
public class NetworkUtils {

public Polyline routeResultGeometry = null;
public List<DirectionManeuver> routeResultDirections = null;

private Context _context;
private final String routeTaskNorthAmerica = "YOUR_NA_SERVER_ROUTE_URL";
private RouteTask _routeTask = null;
private RouteParameters _routeParameters = null;

public NetworkUtils(Context context, GraphicsOverlay routeGraphicsOverlay) {
    _context = context;
    _routeTask = new RouteTask(context, routeTaskNorthAmerica);
    _routeTask.loadAsync();
    _routeTask.addDoneLoadingListener(() -> {
        try {
            if (null == _routeTask.getLoadError() && _routeTask.getLoadStatus() == LoadStatus.LOADED) {
                // route task has loaded successfully
                _routeParameters = _routeTask.createDefaultParametersAsync().get();
                // set flags to return stops and directions
                _routeParameters.setReturnStops(true);
                _routeParameters.setReturnRoutes(true);
                _routeParameters.setReturnDirections(false);

                SolveTest(routeGraphicsOverlay);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("__Leo__", e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

public void Solve() {

    Polyline routeGeometry = null;
    try {
        Stop stop1 = new Stop(new Point(-80.94125, 40.748));
        Stop stop2 = new Stop(new Point(-81.017414, 40.742380));
        _routeParameters.setStops(Arrays.asList(stop1, stop2));

        RouteResult result = _routeTask.solveRouteAsync(_routeParameters).get();
        final List routes = result.getRoutes();
        if (!routes.isEmpty()) {
            Route route = (Route) routes.get(0);
            routeResultGeometry = route.getRouteGeometry();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("__Leo__", e.getMessage());
        Log.e("__Leo__", String.valueOf(e.getCause()));
    }
}

private void SolveTest(GraphicsOverlay routeGraphicsOverlay) {
    this.Solve();

    if (null != routeResultGeometry) {
        SimpleLineSymbol lineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.Style.SOLID, Color.BLUE, 3);
        Graphic routeGraphic = new Graphic(routeResultGeometry, lineSymbol);
        routeGraphicsOverlay.getGraphics().add(routeGraphic);
    }
}
```

}